# Can't call the running rails app docker with boot2docker IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have been trying to test the Fig + Docker + Rails stack on my local machine which run MacOSX.

All of my setups ( Dockerfile, Fig.yml ) and steps are exactly the same as demonstrated fig's official guide.
http://www.fig.sh/rails.html

I use zsh as shell and here is how I export boot2docker env virables.

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://boot2docker:2376
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/tal/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
```

if you cat my /etc/hosts, you would see a host def

```
  wha.eve.rip.use boot2docker
```

My rails app run according to the docker console but can't access it via host with defined port :3000.

What would be the reason that I can't access the rails process from host ?

Please enlighten me , Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to access it via localhost:3000 or boot2docker:3000?  I assume in your case you would want boot2docker:3000.

Also, what does your docker ps output show?  Have you published the ports of your docker container with -P or -p?

Comment: What does the output of docker ps show in your boot2docker terminal?

Comment: @Alex I am accessing it via boot2docker:3000.